Framerate option wont change and is stuck on 30 fps
I updated my Blender to version 4.1.1, but I'm having trouble changing the frame rate from 30 to 24fps. No matter what option I select, it stays at 30fps. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. 

Does is appear in the default scene? If it does, fill a bug report, but bugs are off-topic here. It may be specific for your scene, you can try loading to factory settings

Seems to appear in the default as well! thanks for your reply, I'll fill a bug report
